# Should a list of typos go in thesis defense presentation

Tags: thesis, presentation, thesis-committee, defense

I have a list of about a dozen small errors I've personally discovered in my thesis. Is it advisable to have a slide during the presentation listing these? I understand that this is superfluous, insofar that the examiners will probably already have identified these, but I want to look as if I am aware of them coming into the defense. Is there any possibility it could be considered insulting?

Comment: Are you allowed to still correct the errors?

Comment: If they are not so important, I would not mention them during the defense. If some result you would talk about looks different then in the thesis, you might mention in your talk "btw there was an error in the thesis: it said Thoerem 1 instead of Theorem 1" or whatever. If you should hand the examinators a mistake list: talk about this with your advisor, if you can talk to them.

Comment: Nobody is going to care if your can't spell "Thoerem". But if you have a "small" typo of "<" for ">" in an important equation, that is a different matter!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest a slide for what is probably just a minor matter.

However, you could print out a list of them, deliver them to the committee prior to the event and say they will be corrected in the final version.

It may even happen that one or more of your committee members will have read your dissertation (shocking, I know) and will provide you with a few more.

But for the talk, focus on the insights in the work, not such minor details. Most people attending talks want that, in any case. The details can be found in the paper.

Comment: Having a printout seems like a good compromise. They are minor errors that don't merit any discussion, but having a list to hand would show that I've picked up on them.

Answer (score 1):

If the typos affect the comprehension of your thesis by the reader or twist the results or facts that you have delivered in your thesis, then yes it is definitely a good idea to mention the typos and correct them when you come to the corresponding slide in your presentation.